# DevExpress report: grouping: two groups as one?

Tags: c#, devexpress

Not exactly sure how to phrase this for a google/SO search and I'm not sure what, if any code you would need to see. If you need code, let me know and I'll insert it but at this point, I'm not exactly sure what you'd need. Also, I'm a hardcore "noob" to DevExpress hence my question. I get the idea that this should be a small, simple fix but I don't know how to do it (I'm hoping I'll learn a bit more about devexpress here)

I have a report that uses an `OrderDetail` object which itself has a `byte` field for `status` (which we use a `(byte)enum` to evaluate). Currently, two of the status values (for the sake of this report) are Complete and Paid and in this context both mean the same thing and thus need to be grouped under the "Complete" group.

I've found that if I insert the following code into `subGroupHeader_BeforePrint`, I get them all marked as complete (the Paid status gets a heading of Complete) but Paid items lose all of its grouping (I understand why: I'm handling it on a row by row basis instead of a "whole report" basis)

```
            //not quite it... but gets close. It marks them all as complete but does not group them with complete.
            if (orderDetail.Status == (byte)OrderStatus.Paid)
            {
                orderDetail.Status = (byte)OrderStatus.Complete;
            }
```

**So what I need is an overall way to mark those Paid items as complete without modifying the saved/stored data and then group them with the real Complete items using whatever sorting is already in place.** What do I need to do in order to tell the DevExpress report to handle "Paid" as though they were actually "Complete?" It seems to me that there should be a way to tell the report to do that on a report leel since devexpress seems to be extremely robust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for my particular task is to use a calculated field. Using the instructions found [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument4813), create a calculated field (returning the data type that you want it to be if it's what you don't want (for example, if 50 meant "Paid" and 90 meant "Complete", use the expression building to return 90 if it's Paid and the column value otherwise. In this, case [Status]), set your group header label to use it as well as the group header band/section.